# Is there any way I can inject environment variables into yaml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, yaml, amazon-ecs

I have a dockerfile which accepts variables such as MY_LOCALE such that I have environment variable when the image is run.

And then I want to have a yaml file which will take MY_LOCALE variable so that I can dynamically create docker container with different variable.

It seems as though yaml doesn't support env variable access.

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Not through YAML, you could use shell commands to search and replace in the YAML file.

Comment: Is the YAML file something that's in your own code, or provided by another tool?  If it's, say, Docker Compose, that can [substitute host environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution) in many circumstances.  If it's your own application, accepting environment variables is probably easier to deploy than YAML files.

Comment: @DavidMaze provided by another tool. It seems as though only way to achieve is through code-based approach, which I hoped otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to achieve what you want by using the command `envsubst`.

Write your env variables in your YAML file as $ENV_VAR_TO_REPLACE or ${ENV_VAR_TO_REPLACE}

```
export ENV_VAR_TO_REPLACE=some_value
envsubst < file.yaml.template > file.yaml
```

That will create a `file.yaml` with the env vars replaced.

Comment: Using the Dockerfile [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) mechanism would be simpler, but I don't think this is what the question is asking for.

Comment: Right, I don't know why I assumed that the YAML file was the docker file. Dockerfiles are not written in YAML. But well, the example still works for any YAML file that he would need to apply env var substitution